# Member with #sign

Tags: powershell, xml-parsing

I have code:

```
$doc = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load("http://www2.demis.nl/worldmap/wms.asp?request=GetCapabilities&version=1.3.0")
$layers = $doc.GetElementsByTagName("Name")
```

`$layers` has property `#text`. How can I get its value i.e. in where statement or by dot sign. `$layers.#text` does not work becouse # is treated as comment. I try to escape it but that fails too.

Answer (score 3):

`$object."any string"` can retrieve a complex named properties out of an object. In your case, the code will be `$layers."#text"`.